# Saving serial data to a database using minicom in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, arduino

I am trying to save data counts from an Arduino board to a MySQL database running on Ubuntu. Using minicom, I am able to read the data from the serial port that the Arduino board is connected on, but I am only able to see the data in the terminal. How do I get this data into the MySQL database?

Comment: incklude your tried code?

Comment: thanks. i have figured it out. i had to include myself to the group dialout by doing: sudo usermod -aG dialout <username>

Comment: But now i want to make a loop to be storing the data in the database. the code i have goes through the first loop but fails to execute in the next loops. here is the code:

Comment: where is code? I think you missing it